# disable keys in chrome/Mozilla with plugin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mozilla

I am building a plugin using JavaScript,as part of this i have disabled all the keys but still unable to control the bellow keys , is there any way that i can block the fallowing?

```
     New Window (Ctrl+N)
     Restore Tab (Ctrl+Shift+T)
     Select Next Tab (Ctrl+Tab, Ctrl+PageDown)
     Select Previous Tab (Ctrl+Shift+Tab, Ctrl+PageUp)
     Exit (Alt+F4, Cmd+Q)
     (Alt+Tab)
```

i am trying with registry, is it possible to disable remote desktop when ever the plugin installed?

Comment: @AlonEitan - Pleasant plugin that suits to my application.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn on kiosk mode for the window which makes it full screen and always on top so you can't go to another application.

You could also make the window transparent and position the login in the middle of the screen so it appears as if there is one window in the middle of the screen but you can't click on other areas of the screen.

To handle for Alt+F4 you can use the window.onbeforeunload event or call event.preventDefault() in the close event.

https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#event-close